# create a qrcode with information from database

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I want to implement information from database in my `QR` code. When I create this code, the scanner posts the code `{{ $card->nom }}`

This is my code in my view. Anyone have a solution for this?

```
<div class="visible-print text-right">
{!! QrCode::size('150')->generate(
    '{{ $card->nom }}'                                         
);!!}                                           
</div>
```

Comment: How about using `QrCode::size('150')->generate($card->nom)` instead?

Comment: You don't need to use multiple `{{ }}`; you already have `{!! !!}`, so entering `'{{ ... }}'` inside of those will literally print the string `'{{ ... }}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="visible-print text-right">
{!! QrCode::size('150')->generate(
    '{{ $card->nom }}'                                         
);!!}                                           
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="visible-print text-right">
{!! QrCode::size('150')->generate($card->nom);!!}
</div>
```

Comment: thx how about create  many information can you help me plz its doesn't work with me {!! QrCode::size('150')->generate($card->prenom,
                                        $card->dateAffection,
                                        $card->dateNaissance 
                                        ); !!}